# RxJava + RxAndroid WidgetObservable new API

Tags: android, rx-android, rx-javafx

A few weeks ago this code worked fine with `RxAndroid v0.25.0`

```
Observable<OnTextChangeEvent> usernameObservable = WidgetObservable.text(editText);

usernameObservable
  .filter(e -> e.text.length() >= 3)
  .subscribe(e -> log(e.text().toString()));
```

Since the `RxAndroid v1.0.0` release https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid/releases/tag/v1.0.0

Jake Wharton said that **ViewObservable** and **WidgetObservable**: are available here https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding

And although I have this imports:

```
compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.14'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.0.1'
compile 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding:0.2.0'
```

That code doesn't work and I can't find any documentation.

Do you have any code sample on how to do this simple thing?

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found that `TextView` is the parent of `EditText` so acording to the RxBinding:

```
RxTextView.textChangeEvents(email)
  .filter(e -> e.text.length() >= 3)
  .subscribe(e -> log(e.text().toString()));
```